# Did Freedom System 2.0 used to provide privacy and pseudonymity via onion routing?

Tags: privacy, tor

I have been reading a paper known as "Freedom System 2.0 Architecture" where a user's IP traffic is being transferred between a path of Freedom Server Nodes before reaching to its end destination. It is an obsolete system from millennium's beginning but I want to look to his architecture.

So let suppose I was a internet user at 2000 and have installed Freedom kernel module to my GNU/Linux machine. How traffic would get routed through Freedom Nodes (AIPs) in order to provide me privacy via pseudoanonymity (as far as I've read)?

I try compare it with Tor, in it there is a message sequence that generates a circuit where with the use of Diffie-Hellman through Asymmetric Encrypted Channels is initiated. In Freedom how was implemented?

Did Freedom System 2.0 used onion routing as well, how did they applied encryption on it and what protocols were used in order to provide privacy?

Edit: I understand the principle that we set multiple layers of proxies between network's traffic destination and network traffic beginning, what I am asking how Freedom System 2.0 implemented that.